# unwanted primary keys in a new sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have bulid a new table in my SQL database with the following command :

```
Create Table if not exists Images (ImageID int (10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
         UserID int (10) NOT NULL,
                 Translated tinyint Default 0,
                 DeleteImage tinyint Default 0,
                 DataPosted date,
                 TheImage blob,
                 Translation text,
                 FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

the table is been created just fine, but what i'm checking what was build i've found out that in the table the columns ImageID, TheImage, and Translation are defined as primary keys.
as the query is showing I want only the ImageId to be the primary key.

what's happening here? 
tnx

Comment: How are you checking which columns comprise the primary key?

Comment: i'm using phpMyadmin, and you can see there which column are primary keys (when you enter the table structure)

Answer (score 1):

Seems quite unlikely. It seems far more likely that something is wrong with whatever tool you're using to find out which columns are primary keys.

Actually, from the documentation - here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html - it would follow that a MySQL table can only have one primary key. But even if not, why would you worry about it?

Comment: MySQL can have only one primary key, that means that if I see more then one then the primary key is the triplet (ImageID, TheImage, Translation), I don't want it to be the triplet, just the ImageId

Comment: I'd wager that blob and text columns always count as unique/distinct in MySQL, so there's actually no difference if the triplet is seen as a key or just the integer column. It also won't affect anything else semantically, so there's no point worrying about it. It's probably just MySQL adding indices on blobs and text columns by default as an optimisation or something like that.